# mapping two InfoPath fields to one field in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, infopath, rich-text

I'm very new to InfoPath

I have a very crude ticket system which consists of "summary" and "problem" (a few other fields).

Could I have an InfoPath form that had, for example, multiple questions about creating a new user (First, Last, Display, email, Location) all concatenated into the "problem" field of my ticket system?

(I'm working in SharePoint 2013 on Office 365)

Comment: Is this a list form or a browser form? Can you please try to take more care with spell checking your posts? Three times out of four you spelled the word "field" wrong, and there were many other typos. That makes questions hard to understand. You can help your helpers if you take a little care in writing your question.

Comment: I'm not sure the difference between the two. (I'm goggling it now but if you have any insight into the two that would be helpful)

Comment: Well, are you customizing the form of a SharePoint list or are you creating an InfoPath form from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply take text boxes for all the fields like First, Last, Display, Email etc. and don't bind these controls to SharePoint fields..

Next place a SharePoint field (Problem) in your InfoPath form, but hide it (Rules -> Formatting -> Hide)..

Now set the [Problem field with concatenated formula](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hovsep/archive/2011/07/12/infopath-2010-how-to-concatenate-multiple-fields-some-of-which-are-blank.aspx)

Comment: Could I then have different forms for different types, for example add new user as one form and software request?

Comment: That is completely a different question, please post a separate question for that.. If the answer was helpful, please upvote or mark as answer to close this Question